# Web-specific resources in Flutter

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I'm working on a [Flutter web app](https://flutter.dev/web) and would like to add some web-specific PWA resources such as icons, [manifest file](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest), [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker),...

I've tried to put these files in the `/web` folder but they're not copied into `build/web/` when performing a release build with `flutter build web`.

What is the right approach to deploy these resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the latest versions of Flutter (1.20.0). Previously I had setup a script that did this copy manually, but it's not required anylonger.